# Is there a way to bind a textbox from a report to a checkbox from a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a small project in an Access database. I currently have a Y/N checkbox in a registration form that I want to link to a textbox in a report. For example, when I check the box in the registration form, I want it to automatically input "Y" in a textbox in the corresponding report. I have never written in VB. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this help article that will tell you how to ask questions that will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Checkbox on form is unbound? Expression in report checkbox ControlSource: `=Forms!formname.checkboxname`. No VBA. Or is what you really mean is you want to update field for multiple records in table so it will display in report checkbox bound to field?

Comment: I tried that expression in the ControlSource and it didn't work. I believe the checkbox on the form is bound to the corresponding table.

Comment: So it works, but the problem is that it says Yes for everyone instead of saying Yes for the checked ones and No for the unchecked ones if that makes sense.

Comment: Of course that makes sense if control is calculated and not bound to field. There is only the one checkbox on report so the calculated result is the same for all instances of checkbox. The calculation is not dynamic. It can only take in the one value from referenced form control. Even if form control is bound to field, the value only comes from whatever record has focus.

Comment: Right, so is there a way I can change it to where it shows the value of the specific record?

Comment: Include table with data in report RecordSource? Not enough info to advise specifics.

Comment: Ok. I can try to give some more info. Apparently, this database was created in the late 90s or early 2000s when Access first came out. I have agreed to help out with adding a checkbox or Y/N field for disabilities. Right now, I've got a form that the person fills out with the Y/N checkbox. I then have whatever the checkbox status is update the corresponding table with a Yes or No. This part works just fine; however, I am getting "#Error" on the generated report. The report, as you mentioned in the earlier comment, only takes the value of whatever record has focus.

Comment: The generated report has a textbox that I want to be filled with Yes or No depending on the particular record. I have bound that textbox to the field in the table rather than the checkbox on the form, but still have the error.